# What about a Polemist badge?

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216359/break-statements-in-the-real-world) on Stack Overflow has an accepted answer with a score of -29. Accepted answer was upvoted and downvoted many times. I believe this kind of situation merit a special badge (I would call it **polemist**)

either

- accepted answer of -10

or maybe

- answer **upvoted and downvoted** more than ten times

Others advice ?

Comment: What sort of behavior are you rewarding?  Providing controversial answers?  Many of us are allergic to that sort of thing.

Comment: @Rober, yes that is exactly my answer.

Comment: The point is there is no consensus on such questions, peoples clearly disagree on it. But this is not a flagged answer either. That is not at all the same thing as questions that was just downvoted. ie: there is strong disagreement by part of the community *and* strong agreement by other part. I believe it is aligned with the "there is more than one way to do it' mindset. Also as long as I've seen it's very rare.

Comment: Also, I'm surprised this question was downvoted. Even if the answer is no for good reasons, why not just upvote answers saying 'no' ? I believed downvotes on questions were for questions unclear or that should not be asked... looks like a "don't even think about it" kind of answer :-(

Comment: Downvotes work differently on Meta.  A downvote is "I disagree," and an upvote is "I agree."

Comment: @kriss: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-work/47635#47635

Comment: @Robert and Jon: OK, thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 4):

Why would you want to encourage this behavior with a special badge? Accepted answers appear at the top even if they are in the red. This does not help future users who would be browsing the archives in search for answers.

Comment: My idea was to point out answers that are factual but non consensual. But it's probably not the right way to achieve it, as indeed answers with the change pattern I suggested are more likely to be argumentative than factual and there could be no way to find out automatically.

Comment: Off-topic: too obvious, Joel, we recognized you.

Comment: Jon Skeet, is this you?

Answer (score 0):

That question needs to be closed as S&A. Someone hung a bounty on it, which, like a bunch of garlic on the door, is offering (temporary) protection.

Comment: Um, did you post this answer on the right question? I don't see a bounty here. Since when is anything on meta S&A? S&A is not even a valid close reason on Meta anymore.  Hello?  Anyone home?

Comment: @Robert: see my edit.

Comment: @Rob the linked question, I meant.